# I want to understand theano function(given,updates)

Tags: python, function, theano

I would like to ask a few questions related to theano function.

1.I saw the script in which input variable was not assigned. If so, how it is working?

```
import theano.tensor as T
import theano
# Define symbolic variables
X = T.matrix('X')
w = theano.shared([0.1, 0.1], name='w')
t = T.vector('t')
# Define Loss Expression
L = (t-X*w)**2
# Calculate Gradient Expression
dLdw = T.grad(L, w)
# Compile the training function
lr = 0.1
data_X = theano.shared([[0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.4], [0.2, 0.4]])
data_t = theano.shared([3, 3.5, 4, 4.2])
calc_output = theano.function([], L, 
    updates=[(w, w - lr*dLdw)], givens=[(X,data_X), (t,data_t)] )
for epoch in xrange(100):
calc_output()
```

As you can see above, input square bracket is empty. What is input in this case then?

2.When it comes to 'given' parameter in function, it is a little bit difficult to understand. People say this is for boosting GPU process, but I would like to know what exactly variables should be assigned for 'given'.
Please look at the script below.

```
index = T.scalar('index')
test_model = theano.function(inputs=[index],
outputs=classifier.errors(y),
    givens={
        x: test_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: test_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})

validate_model = theano.function(inputs=[index],
    outputs=classifier.errors(y),
    givens={
        x: valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: valid_set_y[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]})
```

In the given, what x and y do? what colon(:) means? 
As far as I know,(theano homepage says: givens (iterable over pairs (Var1, Var2) of Variables. List, tuple or dict. The Var1 and Var2 in each pair must have the same Type.) – specific substitutions to make in the computation graph (Var2 replaces Var1).) it needs 2 variables but it seems 4 variables in 1st example and 2nd one is pretty complicated to me. Could anyone tell me what given does with specific details? And explain what's going on the 2nd script in given variables.

Furthermore, in the homepage, it says 'you can use the givens parameter of function which replaces a particular node in a graph for the purpose of one particular function.' I don't get what parpticular node in a graph it replaces.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, given means what is the real value of the T variable . IF in the givens there is (x,a) and a is a np.array then it will use a to replace x when it is computed, also in the given if there is x:a, it means the same thing. 
In the first example, data_X is the input, just not given in the first parameter but in givens, which is the same.
In the second example, test_set_x is theano.shared which means its value is already exist, it's a matrix. But which part of it will you use, you will choose by index which is the input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment it is really helpful and please just check that I understood you said. In the first example, given data_x will be input and replace X  with its output(data_x go through 'L' equation:(t-X*w)**2) and then replace x with its output )and this replacement also happened at data_t, since L needs data_x and data_t.

Comment: In the second example, there are two colons. In the first given 'x: valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size', is this(valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size) input and 'x' is replaced one? it is confusing because input is already assigned : input=['index']. I don't get what this 'index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size' part does...let's say batch_sizeis is 100 then it means ' test_set_x[100:200 ]' so replace this test_set_x as x after it went through the output: classifier.errors?

Comment: I also saw that there is only 1 set variable like given=[x,a] which means any number of sets(3 sets or more sets like given=[x,a],[y,b],[z,c]) can be possible?

Comment: In the second example, when the computation is being excuted, x will be replaced by valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]. if gives include x:valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]. But what is the exact index is? Is it 0 or 100? This index is your input. 
I havn't seen "given=[x,a],[y,b],[z,c]", I have seen two kinds of express including givens = {x:X,y:Y} or givens = {(x,X),(y,Y)} which are equivalent.